# Unity: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'image' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax-error, 2d-games

I was trying to make an ammunition counting system with images of bullets that disappear as the character fires the bullets. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7i7CnJblvA):

It seems okay but now I get this error:

> "Assets \ Scripts \ GameFlow.cs (72,28): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'image' could not be found (are you missing a directive
>   or an assembly reference?)"

I can not see the problem. I thought I'd solve by putting "`using UnityEngine.UI;`" but the problem keeps. Anyone know how I can solve it? Thank you.

The code in the Script are:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameFlow : MonoBehaviour
{
public static float remainingShots = 6;
public Transform shot1;
public Transform shot2;
public Transform shot3;
public Transform shot4;
public Transform shot5;
public Transform shot6;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
  if (remainingShots > 0)
  {
    shot1.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    shot1.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = false;
  }

  if (remainingShots > 1)
  {
    shot2.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    shot2.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = false;
  }

  if (remainingShots > 2)
  {
    shot3.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    shot3.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = false;
  }

  if (remainingShots > 3)
  {
    shot4.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    shot4.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = false;
  }

  if (remainingShots > 4)
  {
    shot5.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    shot5.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = false;
  }

  if (remainingShots > 5)
  {
    shot6.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    shot6.GetComponent<image> ().enabled = false;
  }


  if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
  {
  remainingShots -= 1;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Assets \ Scripts \ GameFlow.cs (72,28): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'image' could not be found (are you missing a directive
>   or an assembly reference?)"

Change all your 'image' types to 'Image'.

Comment: So simple, @0xBFE1A8 .  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;
 
public class MyClass : ImageEffectBase { }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**